# Show input in embedded form in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to create an embedded form in symfony2 that will consist of a Contact form that will have embedded a ContactPhonenumber form to add phone numbers.

I have followed the instructions in Symfony2 documentation about embedding forms but I can't find a way to show at least an input field for phonenumbers. If I do it without errors, I only get back a label for the embedded phonenumber form.
How can I show an input there?
My code is:

My two entity form classes:

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder                        
            ->add('contactType')

            ->add('title')

            ->add('name')

            ->add('givenName')

            ->add('middleName')

            /*->add(
                'contactPhonenumbers', 
                'collection', 
                array( 'type' => new ContactPhonenumberType($options) ) 
                )
          */        

            ->add('contactPhonenumbers', new ContactPhonenumberType($options) )
        ;
    }

//.......
//More functions
//.......
}

class ContactPhonenumberType extends AbstractType
{

    public function __construct(array $options=null) {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {    
        $builder                                    
            ->add('position')

            ->add('number')

            ->add( 
                $builder->create(
                    'contact', 
                    'searchable',
                    array( 
                        'data_class'    => '....Bundle\Entity\Contact',
                        'class'         => '....Bundle:Contact',
                        'dataroute'     => '...._contact_searchable',
                        'classlistview' => new ....Bundle\Component\Listview\ContactList
                    )
                )->addViewTransformer( 
                    new NameToIdTransformer( 
                        $options[ 'em' ], 
                        $options[ 'request' ],
                        $this, 
                        array(),
                        '....Bundle:Contact'
                    ) 
                )
            )

            ->add( 
                $builder->create(
                    'phonenumberType', 
                    'searchable',
                    array( 
                        'data_class'    => '....Bundle\Entity\PhonenumberType',
                        'class'         => '.....Bundle:PhonenumberType',
                        'dataroute'     => '...._phonenumbertype_searchable',
                        'classlistview' => new ....\Component\Listview\PhonenumberTypeList
                    )
                )->addViewTransformer( 
                    new NameToIdTransformer( 
                        $options[ 'em' ], 
                        $options[ 'request' ],
                        $this, 
                        array(),
                        '...Bundle:PhonenumberType'
                    ) 
                )
            )
        ;
    }
  }
```

And my function on controller

```
    public function newAction( Request $request )
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = new Contact();


//        $number = new ArrayCollection();
//        $number[] = new ContactPhonenumber();
//        $entity->setContactPhonenumbers( $number );

        $form   = $this->createCreateForm( $entity );

        return $this->render(
            '...Bundle:Contact:new.html.twig',
            array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form'   => $form->createView()
            )  
        );
    }
```

And the form in twig:

```
<div class="widget-body">                               
{{ form_start( form, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-horizontal', 'role': 'form', 'novalidate': 'novalidate' } } ) }}
{{ form_errors( form ) }}                                                                                                                        
{{ form_row( form.contactType ) }}

{{ form_row( form.title ) }}

{{ form_row( form.name ) }}

{{ form_row( form.givenName ) }}

{{ form_row( form.middleName ) }}

------>
{{ form_row(form.contactPhonenumbers) }}
<--------
{{ form_row( form.salutation ) }}

{{ form_row( form.address ) }}

{{ form_row( form.superiorContact ) }}
<div class="form-group">
    <hr>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget( form.submit ) }}
        {{ form_widget( form.cancel ) }}
    </div>
</div>
{{ form_row( form._token ) }}
{{ form_end( form, { 'render_rest': false } ) }}
```

Comment: Please show your current code.

Comment: I'm guessing by default your Contact entity does not have any contact numbers?  Hence, you won't see any on the form.  Add at least one to get started.  And you will need to use the collection form type.  Try implementing the example in the docs then change to your entity.